# Highlight C/C++ Programming Mode in WinEdit 5.5

Tags: c++, c, text-editor

I would like to use Winedit 5.5 to write my C-programs. Does anyone know
how I can activate C/C++ highlighting in this editor? I looked around for
quite a while on google, but I did not come across any easy solutions.

Comment: What's the reason behind Winedit? Would you be willing to use another text edit util instead if it highlighted your code correctly?

Comment: I liked Winedit in the past, it is convenient to have some files open at the same time, which could easily be selected.I would be willing to use a different one, which one would you recommend. Thanks

Comment: Zeus has support for c/c++ - http://www.zeusedit.com

Comment: Oh my: `everybody name your favourite editor please`. But just don't do it here

Answer (score -1):

Try [CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org) instead. It has similar features and is more suited to programming in C/C++ as such.